# Is it possible to download/upload SAP code inspector variants?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I would like to set up a Code Inspector variant in one system and then be able to copy it to another system.  I know that it is possible to transport code inspector variants, but is it possible to copy a variant to a system that is not in the same system landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the transport request as you would normally do and release it via SE10. Then you have to manually copy the transport files from the directories "cofiles" and "data" of your sap system to the destination system, respecting the original file location.

As soon you have done this, go to STMS and attach the request in the transport queue of the destination system. You can find that option in the sapgui menu of STMS. Now you can import the transport request.

Regards,
Christian

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I assume I would have to copy these files at the operating system level, by logging on directly to the application server? My guess is that I would also need some additional authorisation, but fortnunately this is not something that has to happen often, so I could get a Basis person to do it.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. You need access on the file system level.